# UICollectionView with fixed number of columns and dynamic cell height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewflowlayout

A lot of good info about UICollectionView is to be found, but I was unable to answer this:

How would you go about creating a vertically scrolling UICollectionView with a fixed number of columns while the cell has dynamic height.

My plan was to use self sizing cells but since I want a fixed number of columns that would require each cell to have a width constraint that is calculated from the collectionview width, this seems quirky and might give issues when changing device orientation. To be specific I want the collection to have on single column in compact and two in regular.

I also tried implementing `collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath) -> CGSize` on *UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout* this way it's easy to set the width of the cells so it fits the number of columns I want, but it seems it's not possible to combine this with self sizing cell height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper class with following enum.

```
enum DeviceTraitStatus {
    ///IPAD and others: Width: Regular, Height: Regular
    case wRhR
    ///Any IPHONE Portrait Width: Compact, Height: Regular
    case wChR
    ///IPHONE Plus/Max Landscape Width: Regular, Height: Compact
    case wRhC
    ///IPHONE landscape Width: Compact, Height: Compact
    case wChC

    static var current:DeviceTraitStatus{

        switch (UIScreen.main.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass, UIScreen.main.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass){

        case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular):      
            return .wRhR
        case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular):
            return .wChR
        case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact):
            return .wRhC
        case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact):
            return .wChC
        default:
            return .wChR

        }

    }

}
```

Then in the collection view delegate method calculate the width accordingly.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return size(for: indexPath)
}

private func size(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourCollectionViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! BoxSelectCollectionCell

    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Call the method to calculate the width
    var width: CGFloat = 0
    switch DeviceTraitStatus.current
   {
          case .wChR, .wChC: width = (collectionView.frame.size.width - padding/2).rounded(.down)

          case .wRhR, .wRhC: width = (collectionView.frame.size.width/2 - padding/2).rounded(.down)

   }
    let height: CGFloat = 0

    let targetSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

    var size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh, verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)

    return size
}
```

Comment: This does sort of work, but as soon as I add constraints to my cell layout which relates to the width of the cell ie. setting a label to fill the width of the cell the cells shrink down to the label with instead of being 1:1 or 1:2 of the collectionView as required...